# How to integrate gnuplot graphic with a web application?

Tags: html, gnuplot

I create a Html page with 4 grids (Bootstrap). I want to integrate a Gnuplot chart there or generate a chart inside the web application.

What I am trying to do right now is:

1. Give some values to the graphic variable:

   x: 
    y:
2. Try to GET somehow this values and process them with Gnuplot[blocking point]
3. Generate a Gnuplot chart based on the input values[blocking point]

Could someone give me advice? Or how this implementation should be done properly? In case that mine is wrong.

Comment: No, use an appropriate tool for this like [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery)